# What does the | operator do in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, operators

In this answer, the answerer uses the | operator: [Yes/No message box using QMessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13111762)

According to the documentation, that argument is supposed to be `StandardButtons`.

So the `|` operator merges two `StandardButton` into one `StandardButtons`?

I've tried looking through the Qt documentation, but there is none on operators. So it must be a C++ operator?

Comment: I've said this countless times: Learn C++ before Qt!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is the *bitwise OR* operator, which is commonly used to combine enum values (assuming that the integers backing the enum values are powers of two). In this case, the code specifies that it wishes to have both a Yes and a No button. (Note that this is standard C++ syntax and nothing Qt specific.)